# Windows 10 laptop stuck on loading circle

Tags: windows-10

I have a win10 machine that is stuck on the loading screen, possible white circle of death.

I have left the machine overnight to see if will get out of the loop and it did not solve.

I have created a repair USB and booted to that. The start up repair cannot repair.

Tried various fixes to mbr etc nothing is solving...

It seems that i will have to go back to a previous restore point or reinstall windows 10.

Is there any other options out there?

Comment: As you state, a Windows reinstall from a recent ISO should work, and it has option to keep files (though applications may need to be recovered from Windows.old or reinstalled).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following methods:

**Method 1. Perform a System Restore or Startup Repair**

1. Download Windows 10 media creation tool and create a Windows 10 installation media.
2. Boot or start your computer from the Windows 10 installation media.
3. In the Install Windows page, click '**Repair your computer**' to start the Windows Recovery Environment.
4. In the Windows Recovery Environment, on the Choose an option screen, click '**Troubleshoot**'.
5. Click '**Advanced Options**' and then click on '**System Restore**' or '**Startup Repair**'.

Then follow the on-screen instructions to fix Windows 10.

**Method 2: Fix the boot files**

1. Use the installation media to boot into Windows Recovery Environment as above method.
2. In the Windows Recovery Environment, on the Choose an option screen, click '**Troubleshoot**'.
3. Click '**Advanced Options**' and then click on **Command Prompt**.
4. Type these following commands and hit enter after each line of command:

   ```
   Bootrec /fixmbr
   Bootrec /fixboot
   Bootrec /scanos
   Bootrec /rebuildbcd
   sfc /scannow
   Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
   ```

If the issue persists, please backup all important data and then use the installation media to do a Clean installation of Windows 10 1709.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable fast boot in BIOS

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please explain why that would improve things

Comment: @RohitGupta it worked for me, i know its weird